# Iperf for Xmarin forms

Tags: c#, c++, xamarin, iperf

I am trying to build an app which utilizes Iperf under the hood. Preferably I would use Iperf 2.0.5, but I could use iPerf3 if it makes a lot more sense. (I would just also need to change some server code). The source code is [here](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php#source). Since it is written in c/c++ I do not know what the best way to use it is. Do I need to rewrite in c# as a PCL? I wanted to avoid that in case there are errors in the rewrite. I have also looked at shared libraries for c++ but I am hesitant because I think that will have its own issues since it needs to access sockets which are native to the platforms.

Maybe someone has done something similar? I am trying to avoid wasting time attacking this project in the wrong way.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.